# Textarea field value is going out of the page after submitting the form max length allowed is 250, how can we fix this?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Textarea field value is going out of the page max length allowed is 250.
When I enter the value in textarea field which allows characters up to 250 and then created user with this field.
After successful creation of that user if I view that user info the text area value is going out of the page.

how can we fix this?

[image]

Comment: please add your code as minimal reproduciable code snippet (ctrl + m). Max-lenght only limits the characters that can be typed into the texfield not the maximum width of the text-field.

Comment: post your code please  textarea is styled with css  
<style>
textarea {
  // styles here 
}
</style>

Comment: What do you want it to look like? Have you tried using the `word-break` css property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: Thank you all @HåkenLid word-break: break-all; resolved my issue, thanks.